# ListView refresh in a Fragment with SlidingTab

Tags: android, android-listview, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've this problem, i make an app with 3 tab using SlidingTab, in the second of this tab i've 2 ListView and in the first tab i use a ACTION_CAPTURE.
When come back from camera app to the Main Activity and i pass in the second tab both the listview disappeared.
Why?

Comment: Without the code we can only speculate.. if you put your code here, there's a much higher chance, that someone may help you.

Comment: Please add some codes, so that we can check...

Comment: Post the code foe the second fragment. there might be a chance that the second adapter of the listview( Both listview) is not getting update when you slide from the adpater. You can Use adapter.notyfysetDatachange()

Comment: Thx, i add the code of the second tab (sorry if not clear, this is my firts app, and i'm learning now the android programmation)

Answer (score 0):

```
import arrivi.operativi.operativi220.InventarioAdapter.customButtonListener;
import arrivi.operativi.operativi220.invepiazzadapter.customButtonListener2;

public  class InventarioFragment extends Fragment implements customButtonListener, customButtonListener2 {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
private int mPage;
int entrata=0;
private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
private WritableCellFormat times;
Button btNew ;
globalVar g;
inv_list lista = inv_list.getInstance();
inv_list_piaz lista_piaz = inv_list_piaz.getInstance();
ArrayList<inventario> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<inventariopiazzale> lsp = new ArrayList<>();
inventario tmpINV;
inventariopiazzale tmpINVP;
ListView lv;
ListView lvp;
invepiazzadapter adapter_piazz;
InventarioAdapter adapter;

public static InventarioFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    InventarioFragment fragment = new InventarioFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

//@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    //setMenuBar();
    if (entrata == 0) {
        popola_array();
        entrata = 1;
    }

    //ls=lista.getInventarioArrayList();

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
     adapter = new InventarioAdapter(context, R.layout.layout_inventario, lista.getInventarioArrayList());

    adapter.setCustomButtonListner(new customButtonListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position, inventario value, RadioGroup rR, int numAR) {
            if (numAR == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scelta Rimossa! " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                inventario p;
                p = value;
                rR.clearCheck();
                inv_list locale = inv_list.getInstance();
                ArrayList<inventario> tmp = locale.getInventarioArrayList();
                p.setPorta(String.valueOf(p.getPosizione() + 1));
                p.setsR(0);
                p.setcM(0);
                p.setrM(0);
                p.setTarga("");
                tmp.set(p.getPosizione(), p);
                locale.setInventarioArrayList(tmp);
            }

        }
    });



     adapter_piazz = new invepiazzadapter(context,R.layout.layout_inventario,lista_piaz.getInventarioArrayList());
    adapter_piazz.setCustomButtonListner2(new customButtonListener2() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClickListner2(int position, inventariopiazzale iv, RadioGroup rR, int numAR) {
            if (numAR == 2) {

                inventariopiazzale Pi;
                Pi = iv;
                rR.clearCheck();
                inv_list_piaz locale = inv_list_piaz.getInstance();
                ArrayList<inventariopiazzale> tmp2 = locale.getInventarioArrayList();
                Pi.setPorta(String.valueOf(Pi.getPosizione() + 1));
                //btRM.setChecked(false);
                // btCM.setChecked(false);
                // btSR.setChecked(false);
                Pi.setsR(0);
                Pi.setcM(0);
                Pi.setrM(0);
                Pi.setTarga("");
                tmp2.set(Pi.getPosizione(), Pi);
                locale.setInventarioArrayList(tmp2);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scelta Rimossa! " + Pi.getPorta(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_inventario, container, false);
    setMenuBar();
    btNew = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.LVRibalte);
    lvp = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvPiazzale);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvp.setAdapter(adapter_piazz);
    //setMenuBar();
    setLayout(view);
    return view;

}

// Config Layout
public void setLayout(View v)
{
    // Inizializzo Titolo  List
    TextView LabTop = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Inv_Rib_Label);
    Typeface carLabTop = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Sportscenter.ttf");
    LabTop.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    LabTop.setTextSize(18);
    LabTop.setTypeface(carLabTop);
    TextView LabButtom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    Typeface carLabButom = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Sportscenter.ttf");
    LabButtom.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    LabButtom.setTextSize(18);
    LabButtom.setTypeface(carLabButom);
    // Inizializzo le listview


   /** TextView EdTarga = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.num_Porta);
    Typeface carTarga= Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Sportscenter.ttf");
    EdTarga.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    EdTarga.setTextSize(18);
    EdTarga.setTypeface(carTarga);**/

}
// INIZIO TEST ZONE
public void crea_file_excel(){

    final String fileName = "inventario.xls";
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/OA");
    if(!directory.isDirectory()){
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(directory, fileName);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("it", "IT"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook;

    try {
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Invantario Piazzale", 0);
        try {
            sheet.addCell(new Label(0,0,"Porta"));
            //sheet.addCell(new WritableCellFormat().setBorder(Border.BOTTOM, BorderLineStyle.DASHED));
            sheet.addCell(new Label(1,0,"Tipo Pezzo"));
            sheet.addCell(new Label(2,0,"Targa"));

            int conta = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
                tmpINV = ls.get(i);
                sheet.addCell(new Label(0, conta, tmpINV.getPorta()));

                if((tmpINV.getrM() == 0) & (tmpINV.getsR() == 0) & (tmpINV.getcM() == 0))
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "Porta Vuota"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, ""));
                }
                if(tmpINV.getsR() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "Semi Rimorchio"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINV.getTarga()));
                }
                if(tmpINV.getcM() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "CASSA"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINV.getTarga()));
                }
                if(tmpINV.getrM() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "Rimorchio"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINV.getTarga()));
                }
                conta = conta + 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lsp.size(); i++) {
                tmpINVP = lsp.get(i);
                sheet.addCell(new Label(0, conta, tmpINVP.getPorta()));
                sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINVP.getTarga()));
                if((tmpINVP.getrM() == 0) & (tmpINVP.getsR() == 0) & (tmpINVP.getcM() == 0))
                {
                }
                if(tmpINVP.getsR() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "Semi Rimorchio"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINVP.getTarga()));
                    conta = conta + 1;
                }
                if(tmpINVP.getcM() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "CASSA"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINVP.getTarga()));
                    conta = conta + 1;
                }
                if(tmpINVP.getrM() == 1)
                {
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, conta, "Rimorchio"));
                    sheet.addCell(new Label(2, conta, tmpINVP.getTarga()));
                    conta = conta + 1;
                }

            }
        }catch (RowsExceededException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        workbook.write();
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
 super.onResume();
}
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    //Fragment.onActivityCreated(Bundle);
    this.onCreate(null);
}
// FINE TEST ZONE

public void popola_array()
{
    RadioGroup RG=(RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById( R.id.radioGroup);

    globalVar ff = globalVar.getInstance();
    int i =0;
    int pP=ff.getPP();
    int pR=ff.getPR();

    for (i=0;i<pR;i++)
    {
        //  View v = new View (R.layout.layout_inventario);

        // RG.check(R.id.semiRimorchio);
        ls.add(new inventario(String.valueOf(i+1),R.id.semiRimorchio,0,0,0,i,""));
    }
    inv_list tmp = inv_list.getInstance();
    tmp.setInventarioArrayList(ls);

    for (i=0;i<pP;i++)
    {
        lsp.add(new inventariopiazzale("P"+String.valueOf(i+1),R.id.semiRimorchio,0,0,0,i,""));
    }
    inv_list_piaz tmpp = inv_list_piaz.getInstance();
    tmpp.setInventarioArrayList(lsp);
    entrata =1;
}

public void conta_pezzi()
{

    int tmpSR=0;
    int tmpCM=0;
    int tmpRM=0;
    for (int i =0; i<ls.size();i++)
    {
        tmpINV = ls.get(i);
        if(tmpINV.getcM()==1)
            tmpCM =tmpCM+1;
        if(tmpINV.getsR()==1)
            tmpSR= tmpSR+1;
        if(tmpINV.getrM()==1)
            tmpRM=tmpRM+1;

    }

    int tmpSRP=0;
    int tmpCMP=0;
    int tmpRMP=0;
    for (int i =0; i<lsp.size();i++)
    {
        tmpINVP = lsp.get(i);
        if(tmpINVP.getcM()==1)
            tmpCMP =tmpCMP+1;
        if(tmpINVP.getsR()==1)
            tmpSRP= tmpSRP+1;
        if(tmpINVP.getrM()==1)
            tmpRMP=tmpRMP+1;

    }



    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "In ribalta: " + tmpCM +"CM, "+tmpSR +"SR, "+tmpRM+"Rim., a Piazzale :"+ tmpCMP +"CM, "+tmpSRP +"SR, "+tmpRMP+"Rim." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position, inventario value, RadioGroup rR, int numAR) {
    if (numAR == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scelta Rimossa! " + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        inventario p;
        p = value;
        rR.clearCheck();
        inv_list locale = inv_list.getInstance();
        ArrayList<inventario> tmp = locale.getInventarioArrayList();
        p.setPorta(String.valueOf(p.getPosizione() + 1));
        p.setsR(0);
        p.setcM(0);
        p.setrM(0);
        p.setTarga("");
        tmp.set(p.getPosizione(), p);
        locale.setInventarioArrayList(tmp);
    }


}


@Override
public void onButtonClickListner2(int position, inventariopiazzale iv, RadioGroup rR, int numAR)                            {
    if (numAR == 2)
    {

        inventariopiazzale Pi ;
        Pi = iv;
        rR.clearCheck();
        inv_list_piaz locale = inv_list_piaz.getInstance();
        ArrayList<inventariopiazzale> tmp2 = locale.getInventarioArrayList();
        Pi.setPorta(String.valueOf(Pi.getPosizione() + 1));
        //btRM.setChecked(false);
        // btCM.setChecked(false);
        // btSR.setChecked(false);
        Pi.setsR(0);
        Pi.setcM(0);
        Pi.setrM(0);
        Pi.setTarga("");
        tmp2.set(Pi.getPosizione(), Pi);
        locale.setInventarioArrayList(tmp2);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scelta Rimossa! " + Pi.getPorta(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_fragment, menu);
    MenuItem add = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add);
    add.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem setting = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_setting);
    setting.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem foto = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_foto);
    foto.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem send = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_inventario);
    send.setShowAsAction(2);
    setMenuBar();





}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_inventario) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invia Inventario!!", 2500).show();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setMenuBar()
{
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Sportscenter.ttf");
    SpannableStringBuilder SI = new SpannableStringBuilder("Inventario Pezzi");
    SI.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, SI.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    SI.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),0, SI.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    SI.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), 0,SI.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getActionBar().setTitle(SI);

}
```

}